# Cancelling an iOS/UIKit Async Task with a global flag

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, concurrency, uikit

Environment: Swift 5, Xcode 14, iOS 15, UIKit (NOT SwiftUI)

I have a long-running async task which I execute in a Task block:

```
Task { () -> () in
  do {
    for z in arrayData{
      if killTask {        // an external property
        try Task.cancel()  // **Swift Errors here**
      }
      let x1 = try await self.longTask1(z.var1)
      let x2 = try await self.longTask2(z.var2)
      etc.
    }
  } catch { print("Bad") }
}   //  end task
```

This fails with Swift syntax errors that Success and Failure in the Task can not be inferred. The Task produces no Result type.  Can someone please point me in the correct direction by which I can cancel a task (with no input/output/Result types) by an external semaphore condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than introducing a `killTask` property, you can save the `Task` which you can later `cancel`.

So you would have a property:

```swift
var task: Task<Void, Error>?
```

and

```swift
task = Task {
    for z in arrayData {
        try Task.checkCancellation()
        let x1 = try await self.longTask1(z.var1)
        let x2 = try await self.longTask2(z.var2)
        ...
    }
}
```

And later

```swift
task?.cancel()
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, I actually tried that first, but got hung up on the same syntax error where I defined the Task property. I will try your suggestion of using Void and Error as the missing args!

Comment: It turns out by testing that "Cooperative" Cancel actually means killing the task no time soon which means that old, "cancelled" tasks would still contribute to and contaminate resulting data.  The only fix I found that works was to ditch Tasking and use the older completion handler/Closure approach.

Comment: Strikes me that the completion handler/closure approach has the exact same problem (there is no preemptive cancelation), but only worse as it has no native cancelation mechanism. Now you could use `DispatchWorkItem`, which is also cancelable but offers no benefit over the async-await cancelation mechanism. Bottom line, cancelation is always cooperative. There is no preemptive cancelation in either dispatch queues, operation queues, or Swift concurrency. But if you feel more comfortable using legacy patterns, feel free to run with that.

Comment: One thing missing here is setting the `task` property back to `nil` when task is completed. This will free resources associated with the task after the completion of task and you won't be accidentally canceling task after completion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are spawning multiple unstructured tasks, for managing them and handling their cancellation, you can use [`TaskGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/taskgroup) and [`withTaskCancellationHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/withtaskcancellationhandler(operation:oncancel:)) to make your own cancellation handling construct similar to CoroutineScope in Kotlin and CancellationToken in C#. I have written about this in more detail [here](https://soumyamahunt.medium.com/how-to-manage-unstructured-tasks-with-swifts-structured-concurrency-6cc4329b4d13).